# AMQP Laravel-NestJS RPC. Can not create response

Tags: laravel, rabbitmq, nestjs, rpc

I use amq.rabbitmq.reply-to pseudo queue to realese RPC, but cant reach answer for my request. In RPC NestJs publisher - NestJs consumer it work good. But if i switch publisher to Laravel my NestJS Client dont't create response. Laravel publisher:

```
$this->response   = null;
        $this->corr_id    = Str::uuid()->toString();
        $waitingQueue     = 'test_queue';
        $connection       = new AMQPStreamConnection( 'rabbitmq', 5672, 'root', 'root' );
        $channel          = $connection->channel();
        $responseQueue    = 'amq.rabbitmq.reply-to';
        $channel->basic_consume(
            'amq.rabbitmq.reply-to',
            '',
            false,
            true,
            false,
            false,
            function ( $response ) {
            if ( $response->get( 'correlation_id' ) == $this->corr_id ) {
                $this->response = $response->body;
            }
        }
        );

        $data = json_encode( [
            'pattern' => 'test-pattern',
            'data'    => 'some_data'
        ] );

        $msg = new AMQPMessage(
            $data,
            [
                'correlation_id' => $this->corr_id,
                'reply_to'       => $responseQueue,
                'delivery_mode'  => 1,
                'headers'        => []
            ]
        );

        $channel->basic_publish(
            $msg,
            '',
            $waitingQueue,
            true
        );
        while ( !$this->response ) {
            $channel->wait( );
        }
        $channel->close();
        $connection->close();
        dump( $this->response );
```

Nest client:

```
@MessagePattern('test-pattern')
public async getAll(data) {
    const answer = await this.somelogic
    return answer
}
```

Nest Js Publisher:

```
return await this.client.send('test-pattern', 'some_data').toPromise()
```

where client:

```
return ClientProxyFactory.create({
            transport: Transport.RMQ,
            options: {
                urls: [`amqp://root:root@localhost:5672`],
                queue: 'test_queue',
            }
        })
```

It works for Laravel publisher only if i switch NestJs client on custom handler.

```
        @MessagePattern('test-pattern')
public async getAll(@Payload() requestData, @Ctx() context: RmqContext) {
    const channel = context.getChannelRef();
    const originalMsg = context.getMessage();
    const answer = await this.somelogic


    channel.sendToQueue(
        originalMsg.properties.replyTo,
        Buffer.from(
            JSON.stringify({
                data: answer,
            })
        ),
        {
            correlationId: originalMsg.properties.correlationId
        }
    )
    channel.ack(originalMsg)
}
```

But I want to keep the original code so I can switch between different message brokers.

Logs of my messages:
From Laravel:

```
Exchange    (AMQP default)
Routing Key test_queue
Redelivered ○
Properties  
reply_to:   amq.rabbitmq.reply-to.g1h2AA9yZXBseUAxMjU3Mzg4MDYAAGcRAAAAAGHC8ds=.9BLsGuzLIVkwrmFmR4lO6g==
correlation_id: c546bc52-2e8e-4725-96d0-81752f36d597
delivery_mode:  1
```

From Nest:

```
Exchange    (AMQP default)
Routing Key test_queue
Redelivered ○
Properties  
reply_to:   amq.rabbitmq.reply-to.g1h2AA9yZXBseUAxMjU3Mzg4MDYAAGc5AAAAAGHC8ds=.v0yse/O8NTuRgKfRnORs9g==
correlation_id: b2b07701-d25d-4618-b5a8-8b73bf52428d
delivery_mode:  1
headers:
```

Answer (score 1):

After 1 year, your issue has definitely been resolved, but for anyone with the same problem.
NestJs native RabbitMQ library only sends the message to the reply queue if your message contains a key `id` which is a UUID.

Change the following:

```
 $data = json_encode( [
     'pattern' => 'test-pattern',
     'data'    => 'some_data'
 ]);
```

To:

```
 $data = json_encode( [
     'pattern' => 'test-pattern',
     'data'    => 'some_data'
     'id'.     => Str:uuid() // use Illuminate\Support\Str;
 ]);
```